# PhoneGap Cordova YoutubeVideoPlayer Plugin An error this could be due to network issue of YouTube protocols

Tags: ios, cordova, youtube, phonegap-plugins

I create a "Play Youtube" App with PhoneGap(version 6.3.0) , Cordova (version  6.3.1) , simple  load a youtube video by ID.
use Cordova YoutubeVideoPlayer plugin, using build.phonegap.com to build project, but not working with error:

```
An error occurred during the retrieval of the video. This could be due to network issue of YouTube protocols. Please try again later.
```

I test on android OS  version 6.0.

Thanks in advance.

add to config.xml:

```
<plugin name="com.bunkerpalace.cordova.youtubevideoplayer" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
```

Load youtube video when device ready in index.js

```
 YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo('1s96mq8kfzY');
```

index.js

```
var app = {
     initialize: function() {
         this.bindEvents();
     }, bindEvents: function() {
         document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
     },   onDeviceReady: function() {
         app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
     },   
     receivedEvent: function(id) {
         var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
         var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
         var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

         listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
         receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
         console.log('Received Event: ' + id);        
         YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo('1s96mq8kfzY');
     }
 };
```

index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
     <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" /> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
     <title>Hello World</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class="app">
         <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
         <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
             <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
             <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
         </div>         
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         app.initialize();
     </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.hd.yu" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>YTube2</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="com.bunkerpalace.cordova.youtubevideoplayer" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="57" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="50" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="29" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" platform="ios" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="768" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" platform="ios" src="www/res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="99" />
        <icon height="159" platform="wp8" src="www/res/icon/wp8/Background.png" width="159" />
        <splash height="1280" platform="wp8" src="www/res/screen/wp8/screen-portrait.jpg" width="768" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="30" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="50" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <splash height="300" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
        <icon height="120" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="44" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="310" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="150" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" platform="windows" src="www/res/icon/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
        <splash height="1920" platform="windows" src="www/res/screen/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
</widget>
```

Comment: any solution for this issue?

Comment: Have no good solution. I try with iframe embedded or try with https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference, Youtube video can play but i can't remove the YouTube logo when run on mobile app (it work fine on desktop browser). 
<iframe  width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + '?&theme=dark&color=white&autoplay=1&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>.
I am still finding a best solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found that it's related to the video owner policy, if the video owner choose to restrict the video playback for mobile devices, you will not be able to use it inside your mobile app. Try with other well known videos from youtube, they are working